# Refresh a <div> content on button click in Mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**This is my controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public static string GetCuttentTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

}
```

**This is my view**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}
<div id="div1">
    @Temp.Controllers.HomeController.GetCuttentTime()
</div>
<input type="button" value="Refresh" />
```

I want to refresh the current time on button click. Please Help

Comment: You need javascript/jquery

Comment: Can you please help me with the code?

Comment: If you want the browsers local time or UTC time, you can use the [javascript  Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Otherwise use ajax to call a server method that returns the date and update the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this as follows:

```
$("input" ).click(function() {
  $("#div1").load('@Url.Action("GetCuttentTime")');
});
```

You would need to change your controller action to this:

```
public ActionResult GetCuttentTime()
{
      return Content(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

Also change your div to this:

```
<div id="div1">    
</div>
```

Removing your controller code.

**Screen shot**

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Its showing error in controller action on return content that, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'system.web.mvc' controller.content(string)'"

Comment: and in the view on @url.action its showing conditional compilation is turned off.

Comment: @Amit Please re-check my question, the controller method needed changed and you needed to remove the controller razor code. See working screen shot.

Comment: need help... Mr.Hutchonoid

Comment: @Amit No problem, I would create a new question if it is different from the above. You will most likely get a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) you returns Json: return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

2) you put returned Json object to the div's value: $("#" + area).text(data);

that's why you end up with json's representation inside div

You need to change it as follows:

1) assume you put html for that div to model's field called NewHtml

2) eptract html from the property of returned json: var returnedHtml = data.NewHtml;

3) use html() method instead of text(): $("#" + area).html(returnedHtml);